# Compiling Mosquitto Authentication plugin

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have mosquitto server installed in debian. Now I am trying to install mosquitto authentication plugin.

In oder to compile the plugin I need mosquitto location path to supply at MOSQUITTO_SRC= in the config.mk.

I have tried /var/lib/mosquitto  and /etc/mosquitto without success. Checked manually in /usr/local/....    nothing.

What is mosquitto path exactly?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is path to mosquitto source code. You can download it from here :
https://mosquitto.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

The Authentication plugin requires access to some of the source files from the actual source for the mosquitto broker. Those files are not normally included in the mosquitto-dev package that you can install via apt-get.

You need to check what version of mosquitto that was packaged for debian (the default one is normally pretty old) and then find the matching source bundle from http://mosquitto.org/files/source/.

You should unpack this and set the MOSQUITTO_SRC variable to point to the unpacked version.

You will also need the dev packages for which ever backend you choose to enable.